# ASP .NET MVC RAZOR - Wrong Function Call

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have 2 seperate views and each of them call upon a controller that uploads a file. They both work okay the 1st time I use them, however for some unkown reason when i switch views the controllers from each view are swapped!! I double checked and i call each controller correctly. So i have no idea why the controllers are swapped between views!

Here is where I input the file:

```
<div class="options">
    <input type="button" id="importexcel" name="importexcel" class="k-button" value="Select Excel File" />@*@T("Admin.Common.ImportFromExcel")" />*@
</div>

using(Html.BeginForm("GetFile", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { EncType = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <br />
}

<div id="importexcel-window" style="display:none;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("GetFile", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
        <table style="text-align:left;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <em>@T("Admin.Catalog.Products.List.ImportFromExcelTip")</em>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @T("Admin.Common.ExcelFile"):
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" id="importexcelfile" name="importexcelfile" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" class="k-button" value="@T("Admin.Common.ImportFromExcel")" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#importexcel").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var window = $("#importexcel-window");
            if (!window.data("kendoWindow")) {
                window.kendoWindow({
                    modal: true,
                    width: "400px",
                    title: "@T("Admin.Common.ImportFromExcel")",
                    actions: ["Close"]
                });
            }
            window.data('kendoWindow').center().open();
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is the respective controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetFile(int Id, HttpPostedFileBase importexcelfile)
    {
        /* read data from file */
        var file = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
        FileChoosen = true;
        FilePath = importexcelfile;
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            /* load and show data */
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Administration/Content/Excel/"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = Id });
    }
```

As mentioned above i have another input controller alike to this one in a different view with a different name: (notice its exactly alike the one on top but with a different name "GetXML" and "importXMLfile"

Here is the controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetXML(int Id, HttpPostedFileBase importXMLfile)
    {}
```

And here is where i input it:

```
<div id="importexcel-window" style="display:none;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("GetXML", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
        <table style="text-align:left;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @T("Admin.Common.ExcelFile"):
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" id="importXMLfile" name="importXMLfile" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" class="k-button" value="@T("Admin.Common.ImportFromExcel")" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
```

Comment: By controller you mean a method in the same controller? Or two different controller classes with one method each. In any case please use proper readable file naming, change GetFile1 to something more related to what it does and only after that attempt to solve this

Comment: two different controller classes with one method each. Okay I will swap out the name

Comment: If you have two different controller classes, why are both of those forms be using the ProductController?

Comment: Sorry i was wrong i have a Controller Class named product, and GetFile and GetXML are 2 functions in them

Comment: Is it the actual Action that is wrongly called, or is it that var file = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0]; is the wrong file? You should probably get your file from the HttpPostedFileBase argument in your method.

Comment: The action is wrongly called